# Sum of multiple records from joined table?

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
select a,b,c
from
table
```

Now I have another table which has hoursWorked in it. Basically I want the sum of anotherTable.hoursWorked where anotherTable.a = a and anotherTable.b = b and anotherTable.c = c.

What kind of query do I need to do this?

Thanks

Something like this:

```
SELECT DATE, CUSTOMER, SUM(FKEY.HOURSWORKED)
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 FKEY ON FKEY.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMER, FKEY.DATE = DATE
```

Comment: Posting some example data and the specific result set you would like for that data would make your question more clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear,couldyou add sample data and sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(at.hoursWorked)
FROM
    anotherTable at
    JOIN (SELECT a, b, c FROM thisTable) t
    ON at.a = t.a AND at.b = t.b AND at.c = t.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your example SQL so that it works:

```
SELECT TABLE1.DATE, TABLE1.CUSTOMER, SUM(FKEY.HOURSWORKED) AS HOURSWORKED
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 FKEY
ON FKEY.CUSTOMER = TABLE1.CUSTOMER AND FKEY.DATE = TABLE1.DATE
GROUP BY TABLE1.DATE, TABLE1.CUSTOMER
```

The most important change is that I've added a `GROUP BY` clause.